# Pandas - Generate string permutation at fixed location

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to generate possible permutation from a string such that the permutation happens only at fixed location

example string - `'ABC|DE|F'`

Expected outcome:

```
ABCE
ABCF
ABDE
ABDF
```

You can read example string as position 0 and 1 have no permutations where as position 3 and 4 can have 2 each. Let me know if additional clarification is needed. Thanks

Edit - C and D cannot occur together. Same for E and F

Comment: Is it a rule also that `C` and `D` should not exist together? Because, i see ABCD is not included in the outcome

Comment: can you clarify the logic?  Its unclear what the rule is you're looking for

Comment: You could look at [`sre_yield`](https://github.com/google/sre_yield), which allows you to generate all possible matches of a regex. In your case, it would produce your expected outcome.

Comment: @seyi - yes, that is correct

Comment: What is the issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC - Thanks for the link. I will use it to frame my questions cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. I used regex for forming the lists of possible letters for each position then i generated the strings.

```
from re import search
def bkt(l, s=""):
    if not l:
        print(s)
    else:
        for i in l[0]:
            bkt(l[1:], s+i)

string = 'ABC|DE|F'
l = []
while string:
    find = search("[A-Z](\|[A-Z])+|[A-Z]", string)
    l.append(string[find.span()[0]:find.span()[1]].split("|"))
    string = string[find.span()[1]:]
bkt(l)
```